# MS Access - link to query in another Access database

Tags: database, ms-access

How can I link query from another MS Access database? I know I can [easily link tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-HA001227658.aspx#BM3), But I don't know how to link queries. The query takes data from many tables which I don't want to link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT [RemoteQueryname].* FROM [RemoteQueryname] IN 'C:\RemoteDatabase.mdb'
```

I have tested with databases locally on my machine and runs flawlessly.  The only note I would like to point out is before running the query check to make sure the remote databse is closed or it will crash the one trying to do the query.

Comment: So, I guess there is no more "official" way to do it?

Comment: @Tomas What do you mean there is no official way to do it?  That is the official way to do it.  According to the Microsoft Access for the select statement it lists `SELECT [predicate] { * | table.* | [table.]field1 [AS alias1] [, [table.]field2 [AS alias2] [, …]]} FROM tableexpression [, …] **[IN externaldatabase]** [WHERE… ] [GROUP BY… ] [HAVING… ] [ORDER BY… ] [WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION]` This is the correct way to do it. [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821148.aspx)

Comment: @reference - I meant more official like if you link tables, you can do it directly using "Link table" without any "hacks" (though I know that one can have different opinion on what is hack and what it is not :-))

Comment: Of course I forgot to close the "remote" database but it didn't crash!

Comment: Amazing. I was able to use the following in the front-end DB no problem
`DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO [linked table] IN '[back-end db] FROM [back-end query] IN '[back-end db]';"`

Comment: It is great way even I could link to a linked table in another database. 1000 Likes

Answer (score 0):

The "official" way, by which I assume you mean using the buttons on the ribbon, TMS, would be to use a Make Table Query. Of course, to update the linked data, you would have to run the make table query every time.