# Fully Qualify MS Access Table

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access query, which references a table: dbo_table2

However, I have moved this table to another database, so I need to fully qualify to restore the links.

```
SELECT table1.x, table1.y, table2.z

FROM dbo_table1 

INNER JOIN dbo_table2
ON (dbo_ID = dbo_ID)
```

Both tables are being pulled from SQL tables.
In my Access query I have added table2 as a Linked Table.
But I'm unsure of Access syntax. If I was using SQL, I would simply use "newdatabaseDB.dbo.table2".

My question is how can I correctly name the table2 reference by fully qualifying the database and table name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access - link to query in another Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786296/ms-access-link-to-query-in-another-access-database)

Comment: If you need to join the table, you can just use the `IN` keyword with a subquery (`INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo_table2 IN 'C:\db.accdb) As Table2 ON ...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it!

By creating a link to an external table in the database where the query was created, Access then treats the table in the queries as if it were local (so no fully qualification needed).

Comment: What's the point repeating a less complete version of my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

If you moved your table to another db, just Link that table in your current db. This way you can use just as it was local.
There is another option, using `IN`:

```
select * from clients in 'c:\test\mydb.mdb'
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3123395/78522

Comment: It's being used in a Join. So my main table is local, but the joined table is now external.