# Can I create "linked" access objects (queries, macros etc.) (similar to "linked Tables")?

Tags: ms-access

I am aware of [MS Access - link to query in another Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786296/ms-access-link-to-query-in-another-access-database) from a number to years back.  My need is not so simple.
We have a number of MS Access ACCDBs which use linked tables to perform certain activities on linked tables (in both SQL Server DBs and local MDBs/ACCDBs).  They consist of a very large number of queries and macros etc.

Each ACCDB references the main database using the linked tables and we have a small number of such databases with different content but identical structure.  In the past, we have used some VBA code to re-link the main database. But the content is now significantly different in the main databases that we'd like to create a separate ACCDB for each content type.  Naturally, because they are dealing with identical structures, a significant (>75%) portion of the objects (queries, macros, tables etc.) are notionally identical.  Is there any way to create a "container" for the common stuff - similar to an ACCDE to hold the common stuff and reduce the maintenance burden as the common stuff "evolves" in one ACCDB (and needs to be distributed to the other ACCDB)?
We use the full range of Access objects - including all "action" query types, macros, linked tables etc.
The referenced link only allows selection queries.  It doesn't seem as though "action" queries and macros can use the same kind of syntax to access the items in the external DB.

TIA,
Paolo
[Edit:  To be clear, I need to run the stuff in the "library" DB in the context of the main ACCDB.  Thus if I have a query "Select * from myTable" stored in the Library DB when I run it, it needs to reference the myTable in the ACCDB not the one in the library (if I even need one there)]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *reference* to a "library" database, and that will give you direct access to the code in that database.

To access queries, you can open the external database, but queries will run in their external context, not in the current (local) database. However, the tables you have linked in the current database can be linked as well in the external database. This way it doesn't matter where the query runs.

Comment: Thanks, Gustav, two points.  I'm not sure how to create such a generalised reference.  Can you provide a sample (notwithstanding my next comment)?  But more importantly, if the queries execute in the context of the library DB, then I'm back in the same place, just once removed.

Comment: Go to the VBE and menu Tools, References. Add the external db as a reference. But it is for code only.